# WiFi Internet connection for after some time

Tags: networking, wireless, internet

I have had some problems with WiFi on my computer.

After a few minutes (random time), the internet stops working on it, however I can still see the other networks available for connection via WiFi and I can also access the IP that gives access to my router.

This happens in Ubuntu 16.04 and 18.04.

I have a Windows partition on the same machine and this does not occur on it.

What can it be?

```
    $ lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list
    03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [168c:003e] (rev 32)
        Subsystem: Dell QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [1028:0310]
        Kernel driver in use: ath10k_pci
        Kernel modules: ath10k_pci
    04:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Qualcomm Atheros QCA8171 Gigabit Ethernet [1969:10a1] (rev 10)
    0: hci0: Bluetooth
        Soft blocked: yes
        Hard blocked: no
    1: phy0: Wireless LAN
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no

$ dmesg | grep ath10k
[    4.924654] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    4.926447] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: pci irq msi oper_irq_mode 2 irq_mode 0 reset_mode 0
[    5.210002] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for ath10k/pre-cal-pci-0000:03:00.0.bin failed with error -2
[    5.210009] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for ath10k/cal-pci-0000:03:00.0.bin failed with error -2
[    5.210210] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for ath10k/QCA6174/hw3.0/firmware-6.bin failed with error -2
[    5.210214] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for ath10k/QCA6174/hw3.0/firmware-5.bin failed with error -2
[    5.211949] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: qca6174 hw3.2 target 0x05030000 chip_id 0x00340aff sub 1028:0310
[    5.211950] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: kconfig debug 0 debugfs 1 tracing 1 dfs 0 testmode 0
[    5.212294] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: firmware ver WLAN.RM.2.0-00180-QCARMSWPZ-1 api 4 features wowlan,ignore-otp,no-4addr-pad crc32 75dee6c5
[    5.277471] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: board_file api 2 bmi_id N/A crc32 20d869c3
[    5.866535] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: htt-ver 3.26 wmi-op 4 htt-op 3 cal otp max-sta 32 raw 0 hwcrypto 1
[    5.959759] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0 wlp3s0: renamed from wlan0
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list` terminal command.

Comment: @Pilot6 log added